# Add different object states to a list

Tags: python

I would like to put a list of operations (each operation is described by a corersponding class) and then let my runner class loop over it and execute them accordingly to some rules. Some operations may appear in the list several times, with different parameters. However, each operation has some internal data that is supposed to be computed once and reused for later calls.

My idea was to create the operation only once and then just modify attributes that vary. However this does not work.

My test code:

```
class my_op_class(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.data = 1

lst = list()
my_op = my_op_class()

my_op.param = 2
lst.append(my_op)

my_op.param = 3
lst.append(my_op)

for l in lst:
    print l.data, l.param
```

I expected the output as follows:

```
1 2
1 3
```

Those good in python would have seen that both entries in the list will have param=3.

I more or less understand why, but I don't see how to get the behaviour I expect.

Comment: It's not clear why you expected the output you did. You're *explicitly* changing the attribute on *exactly the same object*, which is referenced twice in the same list. Why not create two instances of the class, and make `data` a parameter of `__init__`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your list is referencing multiple copies of the same object.  The object has a single param value, so when you change the param value, it changes it on all the references.

You need to create a new instance each time you add it to the list.  You can do that by calling the constructor directly:

```
class my_op_class(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.data = 1

lst = list()

my_op = my_op_class()
my_op.param = 2
lst.append(my_op)

my_op = my_op_class()
my_op.param = 3
lst.append(my_op)

for l in lst:
    print l.data, l.param
```

or you could use [copy.deepcopy](https://docs.python.org/2/library/copy.html#copy.deepcopy) to create a new instance each time you append to the list:

```
import copy

class my_op_class(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.data = 1

lst = list()
my_op = my_op_class()

my_op.param = 2
lst.append(copy.deepcopy(my_op))

my_op.param = 3
lst.append(copy.deepcopy(my_op))

for l in lst:
    print l.data, l.param
```

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't see any difference between two code snippets.<br/>Other than that, my idea was to keep "data" all over the process, e.g.  calling the operation once would initialize data and all all other calls will reuse and update it. From what I understand reading answers here, my approach is not appropriate. Do I have to create another question for it?

Comment: Whoops, I copied the wrong snippet in the first one.  I updated it.  If it's just simple data, I'd recommend just using a dictionary instead of a class and appending my_dict.copy() to the list each time you add it to the list.

Comment: I tag it as accepted as it made me really understand I was on the wrong way. Finally went to a list of tuples like [ (op, param1), (opn param2) ]